# Can not access server when stop mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have used mysql as adapter of rails application. I want to upgrade mysql server so I stop and upgrade it. Why I do not access any url while upgrade it? Although this url can not need to query to Mysql server?

Comment: You need to add some more information.  Eg, did you successfully upgrade MYSQL?  Did you restart MYSQL after upgrading it?  Is your rails server running?  Can your rails server connect to mysql?  (Test this in the console)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Sorry, my question is, when I stop mysql server and start rails server I can not access any url. I know this error is `Can't connect to local MySQL server... `. But I want to know why it have an error? Although this url do not need to query to Mysql server.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Rails tries to connect to the database server when it boots. Therefore, if you stop your database server, you can't start your Rails application.

As long as ActiveRecord is loaded or used, that's the default behavior.